# NSURLSession notify when all tasks are completed

Tags: ios, ios7

I have been reading through the documentation and looking online but have not been able to find a way of doing this. Currently, I am creating 20 tasks in a session and would like to have a way of executing some kind of callback only when all 20 tasks for that session are completed. Is there a way to do this? I have looked at a lot of delegate methods and found nothing of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to track this yourself. Consider keeping an array of task objects. As you start a task, add the task object to the array. When the task is finished, remove the task object from the array.

When you arrive at zero tasks in the array, you are done.

Comment: You don't have to keep an array of tasks , you can get the tasks from the URLSession instance with getAllTasks method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling these tasks sequentially all you must do is spawn the next task when the former task ends in `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location` whilst you keep track of a counter variable. For example:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{

    //Write your file to disk here

    //-nextResource will return the next resource in your array or nil
    NSURL *nextResource = [self nextResource]; 

    if(nextResource)
        [self downloadResourceWithURL:nextResource];

}
```

Comment: For performance reasons, I wouldn't be able to do it this way. I'd like to send the requests to the server all at once.